# How can I get emailed birthday reminders from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, reminder

Several years back, Facebook used to send birthday reminders via email. They stopped doing it in favor of the "birthday ticker" on the home page. Problem with this is, you only see the ticker if you're actually on Facebook. I don't visit the site every day, and I've missed a number of friends' birthdays.

Is there a way to get my emailed reminders again? (Hopefully without needing to use one of the annoying third-party apps that want access to all kinds of permissions.)

Answer (score 3):

Go to the [Gear Icon > Account Settings > Notifications > Emai](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=notifications&section=through_email&view)l, then check if it's set to either 'All notifications, except the ones you unsubscribe from' or 'Important notifications about you or activity you've missed'. Also, check if you've unsubscribed to emails about Birthday Reminders. If yes, click on the corresponding 'Turn On' link.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I'm at home - can't access FB at work.

Comment: Looking at my settings, I'm not unsubscribed to birthday reminders. My email notifications is set to the first option (all except ones I unsubscribe to.) Not sure what else I need to do.

Comment: @EmmyS Are you getting other Facebook notifications in your email inbox? Check if you have the correct email address set at General Account Settings > Email.

Comment: Yes, I had the correct email address set.

Answer (score 0):

My facebook account is temporary locked and i forget my date of birth so how can i login to my account please send me my date of birth on my mail id?
Name:-Anup Ale Magar
ramil:- mohitpun325@gmail.com

Read more: My facebook account is temporary locked and i forget my date of birth so how can i login to my account please send me my date of birth on my mail id? - My account name is shama mishra OK OK :: Ask Me Fast at https://www.askmefast.com/My_facebook_account_is_temporary_locked_and_i_forget_my_date_of_birth_so_how_can_i_login_to_my_account_please_send_me_my_date_of_birth_on_my_mail_id-qna4827023.html